# Is there any node module to auto start application?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm making the application and I need it to autostart when smartphone turns on or restart or when the application is killed. Could someone suggest me some node module to solve this problem?

I'm making the app in react-native.

Comment: Why do you want a node module for this...

Comment: If there is some better way to do this using react native I would be really grateful to hear it.